# Error running new gwt app in hosted mode, OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, gwt, osx-snow-leopard

I just created a new project using webAppCreator from GWT which worked fine. However, when I try to run `ant hosted` it fails with the following output:

```
 [java] On Mac OS X, ensure that you have Safari 3 installed.
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load required native library 'gwt-ll'.  Detailed error:
 [java] Can't load library: /usr/local/gwt-mac-1.7.1/libgwt-ll.dylib)
 [java] 
 [java] Your GWT installation may be corrupt
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.LowLevel.init(LowLevel.java:106)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.mac.LowLevelSaf.init(LowLevelSaf.java:135)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.BootStrapPlatform.initHostedMode(BootStrapPlatform.java:68)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.HostedModeBase.<init>(HostedModeBase.java:362)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.SwtHostedModeBase.<init>(SwtHostedModeBase.java:127)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.HostedMode.<init>(HostedMode.java:271)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.HostedMode.main(HostedMode.java:230)
```

Related ANT task "hosted":
`<target name="hosted" depends="javac" description="Run hosted mode">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.HostedMode">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="src"/>
        <path refid="project.class.path"/>
      </classpath>
      <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
      <jvmarg value="${XstartOnFirstThreadFlag}"/>
      <!--<jvmarg value="${d32Flag}"/>-->
      <jvmarg value="-d32" />
      <arg value="-startupUrl"/>
      <arg value="MyApplication.html"/>
      <!-- Additional arguments like -style PRETTY or -logLevel DEBUG -->
      <arg value="com.disney.MyApplication"/>
    </java>
  </target>`

Comment: Do you have safari 3?  That's what it is looking for.  Don't be alarmed by the word "corrupt" (at least, not in this context).

Comment: Well I actually have Safari 4. I figured as long as it was Safari 3 or later. Perhaps not though.

Comment: However, I do have the following file:
/usr/local/gwt-mac-1.7.1/libgwt-ll.jnilib

It's like the Hosted Mode is looking for the wrong file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy or make a dynamic link of libgwt-ll.jnilib to libgwt-ll.dylib and try it again.  Looks like someone else had a similar issue when using SoyLatte JVM.  Details can be found [here](http://gavintech.blogspot.com/2008/07/soylatte-and-gwt-retreat.html).

Comment: You know, I saw that very article and tried exactly what you said but sadly it didn't work. In fact it made the error worse by still throwing in the same spot but not reporting an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your hosted session is probably running in 64 bits and needs to run in 32 bit.  See [here](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2009/09/gwt-171-release-fixes-mac-os-x-snow.html) for full details.  Basically add the **-d32** flag to the vm arguments in the Arguments section of the run configuration.  You should only have to do this for run configs that  existed before updating to 1.7.1.  When I create a new run config the -d32 is populated for me.

Comment: Thank you but I'm already doing this, at least I think I am. See my ant task below:

Comment: <target name="hosted" depends="javac" description="Run hosted mode">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.HostedMode">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="src"/>
        <path refid="project.class.path"/>
      </classpath>
      <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
      <jvmarg value="${XstartOnFirstThreadFlag}"/>
      <!--<jvmarg value="${d32Flag}"/>-->
      <jvmarg value="-d32" />
...